# Ambiguity between two buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I create a new button which has similar functionality from a another button. So I copy and past the code from the previous button and change it according to new button. But I had an error like - Error    23

Ambiguity between 'UHFDemo.R2000UartDemo.btnConnectArduino(object, System.EventArgs)' and 'UHFDemo.R2000UartDemo.btnConnectArduino'

```
// btnConnectRs232
//this.btnConnectRs232.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans 
Serif", 
7.8F);
this.btnConnectRs232.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int) 
(((byte) 
(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(13)))), ((int)(((byte)(51)))));
this.btnConnectRs232.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 89);
this.btnConnectRs232.Name = "btnConnectRs232";
this.btnConnectRs232.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 25);
this.btnConnectRs232.TabIndex = 2;
this.btnConnectRs232.Text = "Connect";
this.btnConnectRs232.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.btnConnectRs232.Click += new 
System.EventHandler(this.btnConnectRs232_Click);
// 
// btnConnectArduino
// 
this.btnConnectArduino.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans 
Serif", 
7.8F);
this.btnConnectArduino.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int) 
(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(13)))), ((int)(((byte)(51)))));
this.btnConnectArduino.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 89);
this.btnConnectArduino.Name = "btnConnectArduino";
this.btnConnectArduino.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 25);
this.btnConnectArduino.TabIndex = 2;
this.btnConnectArduino.Text = "Connect";
this.btnConnectArduino.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.btnConnectArduino.Click += new 
System.EventHandler(this.btnConnectArduino_Click);
// 
private void btnConnectArduino(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Processing serial port to connect reader.
string strException = string.Empty;
string strComPort = cmbComPort.Text;
int nBaudrate = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBaudrate.Text);
int nRet = reader.OpenCom(strComPort, nBaudrate, out strException);
if (nRet != 0)
{string strLog = "Connection failed, failure cause: " + strException;
WriteLog(lrtxtLog, strLog, 1);
return;
}else
{
string strLog = "Connect" + strComPort + "@" + nBaudrate.ToString();
WriteLog(lrtxtLog, strLog, 0);
}
//Whether processing interface element is valid.
SetFormEnable(true);
btnConnectArduino.Enabled = false;
btnDisconnectRs232.Enabled = true;
//Set button font color.
btnConnectArduino.ForeColor = Color.Black;
btnDisconnectRs232.ForeColor = Color.Indigo;
SetButtonBold(btnConnectArduino);
SetButtonBold(btnDisconnectRs232);
}
private void cmbComPort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
}
```

Now I can't even see the design. Please help me

Comment: You've declared `btnConnectArduino` as both a method and a field. I would suggest renaming the method.

Comment: `this.btnConnectArduino` is a button and `private void btnConnectArduino` is a method.. That's why you are getting this error. You can not have two members in the form with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ambiguity is caused by your button name being the same as your method name, `btnConnectArduino`. Changing one of them will fix your issue.

Comment: Also, event handlers usually have the name `<object that is event sender>_<event name>`, so in this case the method should be named `btnConnectArduino_Click`